# Return list of integers between two cells

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am hoping for a formula or vba function to add a list of values to a cell, given an upper and lower bound. For example, refer to columns A and B in the image below:

[image: Example]

I would like to generate a formula or function that returns a list of both the upper and lower bounds, as well as, all the values in between. See column C in the example above for the desired output.

The issue is the the range between the two cells vary (the output in column C will not always contain 4 integers - it could be more or less).

Does anyone know what the best way to accomplish this task would be? I really appreciate any and all help.

Comment: What version of Excel?  If it's not Office365 or Excel 2016 then you'll need to use VBA to create a UDF.

Comment: @tigeravatar  See my post below................I have been trying to use *INDIRECT()* within *TEXTJOIN()*, but have had no luck.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Perhaps `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ROW(INDEX(A:A,A2):INDEX(A:A,B2)))` ?

Comment: @tigeravatar  ***PERFECT*** ...................you should post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With VBA:

```
Public Function Seq(n1 As Long, n2 As Long) As String
    For i = n1 To n2
        Seq = Seq & "," & i
    Next i
    Seq = Mid(Seq, 2)
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

In the most recent version of Excel, this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ROW(1:5))
```

will return a sequence of values:

[image]

Perhaps a really clever person can tell us how to replace the *1:5* with cell references.

Comment: I think it's this but unfortunately can't test it not having a recent enough version of Excel =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ROW(INDEX(A:A,A1):INDEX(A:A,B1)))

Comment: @TomSharpe  Thanks!...............the approach works..............I foolishly kept trying variation of *INDIRECT()*

Comment: Thanks - this should also work (having tested it in Google Sheets) =ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ROW(INDIRECT(A1&":"&B1)))) but others have advised me against using it in Excel because of volatility.

Comment: @TomSharpe  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Office365 or Excel 2016 and higher, you can use the TextJoin function like so (entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ROW(INDEX(A:A,A2):INDEX(A:A,B2)))
```

Otherwise you'll need to use VBA to create a UDF as shown in Gary's Student's answer.

Comment: Should mention it needs array-entry

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yeah, just thought of that and updated.